# Error while internationalizing WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, localization, internationalization

I am trying to internationalize a WordPress plugin that I am creating but I had no luck regardless of the documentation.

It seems the error happens when the text domain is loaded since `load_plugin_textdomain('phpp', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');` equals to `false`.

These are the steps I did in order to made this work:

1. Create a `languages` folder within the plugin root.
2. Replaced all the strings with functions `_e()` and `__()` (ie.: `<h1>Hello world</h1>` for `<h1><?php __e('Hello world', 'phpp'); ?></h1>`).
3. Created a `es_ES.po` file with the following content:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Plugin name\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: es_ES\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 3.2.2\n"

msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "Hola Mundo"
```

4. Compiled the MO file with [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) into `es_ES.mo` in the `languages` folder.
5. Loaded the text domain in the main plugin function:

```php
function phpp_load_textdomain() {
    $loaded = load_plugin_textdomain('phpp', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');
    if ( $loaded ) {
        error_log( 'Textdomain loaded successfully.' );
    } else {
        error_log( 'Textdomain not loaded.' );
    }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'phpp_load_textdomain', 99 );
```

With all this, the plugin is still displayed in english. Of course I checked the main language of the WordPress site is spanish and also tried to add the action on the `init` hook.

I have tried replacing the `languages` path with different functions and all of them checks but none of them works:

```php
// Relative path
load_plugin_textdomain('phpp', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/');

// Absolute path
load_plugin_textdomain('phpp', false, WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-name/languages/')
```

So, I don't know what else to test or change in order to make this work. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/load_plugin_textdomain/#comment-1568 advises against doing this during `plugins_loaded`.

Comment: @CBroe I already tried with the `init` hook.

Comment: I'd add some temporary debug code to `load_plugin_textdomain` then, to verify what $path value it actually generates, and check if that is actually the correct path to the language file.

Comment: Not sure how else to debug that but I "var dumped" the function and so the paths and checked them. The functions returned `false` every time.

Comment: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L907-L940 - insert a `var_dump($path);` before the final return statement.

Comment: This is what that prints: `C:\Users\myuser\Local Sites\test\app\public/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages`. Maybe something related to the inverted slashes?

Comment: Nah, PHP should be able to handle those quite fine.

Comment: Can only recommend that you debug a little deeper into the WP code then, and figure out at which point the `false` you get, originates.

Comment: @CBroe, Yeah, not that clever from my end. I wasn't aware the PO and MO files had to include the text domain before. I have debugged the `$mofile = $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo';` and the file name was different so I changed and started to work. Please write an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: You can write a self-answer if you like, after you all you figured out what the actual problem was. I just gave you some little hints on the debugging process ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug the code I created a second function named `load_plugin_textdomain` that allowed me to debug the code step by step with the following code:

```php
function load_plugin_textdomain2( $domain, $deprecated = false, $plugin_rel_path = false ) {
    /** @var WP_Textdomain_Registry $wp_textdomain_registry */
    global $wp_textdomain_registry;

    /**
     * Filters a plugin's locale.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $locale The plugin's current locale.
     * @param string $domain Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.
     */
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', determine_locale(), $domain );

    $mofile = $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo';

    // Try to load from the languages directory first.
    if ( load_textdomain( $domain, WP_LANG_DIR . '/plugins/' . $mofile, $locale ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( false !== $plugin_rel_path ) {
        $path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . trim( $plugin_rel_path, '/' );
    } elseif ( false !== $deprecated ) {
        _deprecated_argument( __FUNCTION__, '2.7.0' );
        $path = ABSPATH . trim( $deprecated, '/' );
    } else {
        $path = WP_PLUGIN_DIR;
    }

    $wp_textdomain_registry->set_custom_path( $domain, $path );

    return load_textdomain( $domain, $path . '/' . $mofile, $locale );
}
```

Then replaced my function call with this:

```php
function phpp_load_textdomain() {
    $lang_path = dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages';
    $loaded = load_plugin_textdomain2('phpp', false, $lang_path);
    if ( $loaded ) {
        error_log( 'Textdomain loaded successfully.' );
    } else {
        error_log( 'Textdomain not loaded.' );
    }
}
```

After debugging the line `$mofile = $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo';` I detected the MO file was misnamed so I corrected it and started to work.

Special thanks to @CBroe who gave me the hints to perform this with the [function URL](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-includes/l10n.php#L907-L940) for instance.